# go back previous segue without loosing tabbar controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, show

I used show(e.g.push) segue in order to display tabbar controller as well,
but i cannot achieve to go back previous event.
This is for modal segue :

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i created an unwind method in the controller that i want to return to.

```
@IBAction func cancelToPlayersViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

then connected a Navigation Bar Button to the Exit item of a DetailViewController

[i followed this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2)